# Does $A\subset(\overline A)^0$ hold in this situation?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand the proof of

> A topological manifold is paracompact if and only if its every connected component is $\sigma$-compact.

and one step is giving me trouble. Here is the proof:
[image]

Why does $$\bigcup_{U_j\cap K_n\neq\emptyset}U_j\subset K^0_{n+1}$$
hold? I tried using the fact that $K_{n+1}=\bigcup_{U_j\cap K_n\neq\emptyset}\overline{U_j}$ by definition and it boiled down to showing $U_j\subset(\overline{U_j})^0$, but googling seems to suggest that $A\subset(\overline A)^0$ doesn't hold in general.

Edit: After thinking about it a bit, maybe $A\subset(\overline A)^0$ holds for $A$ open (and hence for the $U_j$)?
$$A=A^0\subset A^0\cup(\partial A)^0\subset(A\cup\partial A)^0=(\overline A)^0$$
Does this justify the inclusion in the proof? It looks to me as if it does, but I'm still not 100% sure.

Comment: $^0$ denotes the interior, right?

Comment: @FShrike yes, it does.

Comment: Is this a proof from a book? If so, which book?

Comment: @Satana it's a proof from my professor's script.

Comment: You should change your title to: “proving that a set is interior to its closure”, although at first glance I (as someone who doesn’t study topology very much) think that that is immediate from the definition.

Comment: If $A$ is open then $\overline {(A)}^o\supseteq (A)^o=A$... A set $B$ is called nowhere-dense if  $\overline {(B)}^o=\emptyset.$ E.g. in the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ with $B=\{1\}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, really:

If $U_j$ is any of those intersecting $K_n$ (in the union at hand), by definition:
$$\overline{U_j} \subseteq K_{n+1}$$ because $K_{n+1}$ is **defined** to be the "union of the closures of $U_j$ intersecting $K_n$".

So $U_j$ is an open set that is a subset of $K_{n+1}$ and so $U_j \subseteq K_{n+1}^\circ$ almost trivially or by definition.
As this holds for all such $U_j$ it holds for their union too.

Hence the inclusion.
C'est tout.

Comment: That *was* simple... I got so caught up chasing unions of interiors and interiors of unions, I completely overlooked this. Thanks!

Comment: @V.Ch. Thx. Sometimes just read carefully. Glad to help!